# Possible to isolate x for: y = x + sin(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I just recently learned that:

$x = \frac{b}{a + 1}$ when $ ax + x = b$.

This got me thinking about trig functions in a similar format, i.e. can we isolate $x$ for:

$y = x + sin(x)$?

Comment: No. $\qquad{} \qquad{}$

Comment: @ZacharySelk Thx!

Comment: Actually, it is - just not expressible as an a function of elementary functions. Since $sin(x)+x$ is monotone, increasing, it is invertible, in other words there exists a function of $y$, such that $f(y)=x$ and $y=\sin(f(y))+f(y)$ holds.